# Cannot use Turkish characters with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

We have a large SaaS ASP .NET 4.0 application used internationally. We are slowly migrating our classic ADO dataproviders toward Entity Framework.

We use MS Sql server 2008. For Turkish customers we use a Turkish collation "Turkish_CI_AS" for character columns. I.e. 8 bit varchar fields (we don't use 16bit nvarchar columns)

Now I encountered a problem when I add new objects with EF. Special characters like 'ş' are changed:

```
    using (TestEntities myEntity = new TestEntities())
    {
                    MyObject test = new MyObject()
                    {
                        TestString = "baş"
                    };

                    myEntity.MyObjects.AddObject(test);
                    myEntity.SaveChanges();
    }
```

When I step through with the debugger, "test.TestString" is still "baş" in this line of code:

```
myEntity.MyObjects.AddObject(test);
```

However in the database the field "TestString" has the value "bas". The 'ş' is saved as a 's' This does not happen with my old dataprovider methods.

How can I add Turkish characters to my database with EF? Anyone has some good suggestions? I tried quite some things but can't figure it out :)

tnx, Frank

edit

running the profiler on a little test setup shows this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[TestObjects]([TestChar])
values (@0)
select [TestId]
from [dbo].[TestObjects]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [TestId] = scope_identity()',N'@0 varchar(255)',@0='Bas'
```

apparently sql receives the wrong value, it's really .NET who's responsible.

Comment: Have you used the Sql Profiler to see the actual SQL going through?

Comment: Yeah. Plus you seem to think turkish customers never have foreign characters. I would strongly suggest using to NVARCHAR - the rest is gross neglect. Even in Turkey.

Comment: I understand what you're saying. We're dealing with years of legacy code and db schema's. "just switching to nvarchar" is not an option at the moment.

Comment: Note that CLR string is by default using Unicode and this is what you see in the debugger. Then the character is converted to 8-bit and you are losing 'ş'. If you can't change the database to nvarchar you may try converting your string to so that it matches what you have in the database. I would start looking from the Econding class - it can return encoding for a codepage.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured it out. In MySql it is possible to add encoding info in the connection string, Microsoft sql doesn't allow this.

EF seems to determine the encoding by looking at the default database collation. In our setup the database collation was Latin1, while the tables with customer specific data have collation "Turkish_CI_AS".

So I have two options:

1) change the default collation for the whole database (impact on
    system and config tables etc)

2) change my columns to nvarchar

Changing to unicode will be done in the end, for now we'll use some good old ADO.NET which just works! :)

tnx for thinking with me

Comment: SQL Server *doesn't need this*. Mixing up collations is a design issue. EF doesn't use its own driver either, it uses ADO.NET

Comment: they may share a driver, the behavior of the libraries who use the common driver is not the same. But we're 6 years ahead, my problem is solved :)

Comment: On the contrary, it's exactly the same driver. There never was any problem with EF - mixing collations and codepages always leads to problems. It's the same with ADO.NET too - if you use use ADO.NET with `varchar` parameters to store Turkish text on `varchar` field with Latin1 encoding you'll get garbled text.