# Language issue while saving a string into database using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an aspx page with a textbox and button.
When I clicked button, it's sending textbox's text to a function and saves it to database using entity framework. The issue is when I use my local characters in textbox such as ş, ğ, ı, ö , ü, these characters are saved as s, g, i, o, u. What is the problem?

My codes (Product.aspx)

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> 
 <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
```

(Product.aspx.cs)

```
 protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Product p = new Product ()
        {
            Id = Int32.Parse(Session["ProductId"].ToString()),
            Title = txtTitle.Text
        };
        int productId = ProductManager.UpdateProduct (p);
        if (productId != -1)
        {
            // SUCCESS
        }
        else
        {
             // ERROR
        }
    }


  public static int UpdateProduct(Product product)
    {
        using (var context = new LidyaEntities())
        {
            Product pUpd = context.Product.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == product.Id);
            if (pUpd != null)
            {
                pUpd.Title = product.Title;
            }
            return context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Database table (SQL SERVER);

```
  (Id, int)
  (Title, text)
```

Comment: Maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483074/cannot-use-turkish-characters-with-entity-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"N"` to solve this issue..

If you want to insert a string like `"ҤїАͻ"` into Database

Then your Query must be like this

**Query:**

```
INSERT INTO TableName VALUES (N'ҤїАͻ')
```

I think it will solve your problem

Comment: But I dont call a query. I'm using entity-framework's add method.

Comment: @MehmetInce: what is the Data Type you are using to Save this words..?

Comment: I'am saving as 'text' type.

Comment: Ok. Solution is changing datatype text to nvarchar. But why? why I cannot use text type with special chars?

Comment: @MehmetInce: An `nvarchar` column can store any Unicode data but `Varchar` store only `non Unicode` . So changing from `Text` to `NVarchar` get Works..

Comment: @MehmetInce I have the same problem, My Column is already nVarchar, still can't save other languages to DB. Help?

Comment: I have a question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315894/which-collation-to-use-for-russian-german-and-arabic

Answer (score 1):

Start by checking the database and confirm the value is stored properly. If it's not you will need to change the character type set of the string column. But before you do that confirm the text value in the code behind is correct too.

Comment: In database, my string is stored also without special characters. For example it's stored as 'cag'. Not 'çağ'