# Which Collation to use for Russian, German and Arabic

Tags: sql, database, ssms

Which Collation shall I use to save Arabic, Russian, English and German Characters to the Database?

My column setting is `nvarchar(100)`

I have set it currently to:

```
SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1256_CI_AS
```

It is saving Arabic, German and English but I need to save Russian too.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have problems inserting the values.
You need to prepend N before the start of the string, otherwise it doesn't work.

You're doing:

```
Insert 'bla' into your_table
```

instead of

```
Insert N'bla' into your_table
```

SQL server does not have a unicode collation.  
However, there is a binary collation "SQL_Latin1_General_1251_BIN".  
It stores the code points in numerical order, which can be pretty arbitrary. 
It's not culture-specific though (despite the name).

Comment: It worked in SQL Management Studio but, I am usign Entity Framework, How to handle this in Entity Framework?